# Unique Digital Signatures for Identical Audio Files

Tags: audio, digital-signature

I have an audio file I've produced and I would like to send copies of the audio file to some of my industry colleagues.

**Is there a way to create a detached digital signature/seal that is linked to the audio file and unique to the individual recipient?**

**I'm also curious if the digital signature/seal would invalidate if the recipient was to copy or forward the file?**  *(since it is detached as opposed to being embedded in the metadata of the file)*

I'm not concerned with preventing my colleagues from copying or sharing the file publicly, but I am interested in only them having a "signed"/"certified" copy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your question is well stated. The answer is also yes, you can create a standard detached signature (PKCS #7) using various systems. For a secure digital signature, you should use a secure signing appliance.

(Disclaimer: I work for DocuSign.)

CoSign Central from DocuSign handles many digital signature tasks including creating detached signatures for any file format. Later on, the recipients can verify the signature (contained in the separate file) against the data file.

If the signature verifies successfully, that enables the recipient to know that:

- The file was not changed since it was signed
- The signer is the person named in the signature's public certificate
- The signer can't repudiate their signature (they can't successfully claim that they didn't sign the file).

Your specific questions:

> Is there a way to create a detached digital signature/seal that is linked to the audio file and unique to the individual recipient?

Digital signatures are signed by the signer. So you would need the recipients to sign for the file. If you want the sender to sign, the signature would be unique to him or her.

You could add data to the mp3 file that makes it specific to the recipient, eg put the recipient's name into an [ID3 tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3), then you (the sender) would digitally sign the file.

Since the only way the signature passes verification is if the data file is unchanged, the signature would prove that either the file was created for Fred Bloggs, the original recipient named in the ID3 tag, or that the file had been tampered with.

> I'm also curious if the digital signature/seal would invalidate if the recipient was to copy or forward the file? (since it is detached as opposed to being embedded in the metadata of the file)

Copying or forwarding a file does not invalidate the file's associated digital signature. Only changing the file's signed data invalidates the signature.

> I'm not concerned with preventing my colleagues from copying or sharing the file publicly, but I am interested in only them having a "signed"/"certified" copy.

Recipients could send the file to a bad guy, Mr. X. If they also send Mr. X the detached signature file, then Mr. X would be able to verify the signature, if he wanted to. (But why would he?)

If a recipient sends the file to Mr. X and Mr. X changes the ID3 tag to his own name or just removes the tag, Mr. X would not be able to produce a matching detached signature file since only you can do that. (But who or what would force Mr. X to produce the matching detached signature file?)

Mr. X would still be able to play the file, make and distribute copies of it, etc. Digital Signatures by themselves are not a digital rights system since they don't include an enforcement mechanism, only a verification mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You could employ forward secrecy techniques on said digital signatures, requiring that the certification only attaches upon initial send of the file.